# Is there always one integer between these two rational numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, inequalities, diophantine-equations, open-problems

It appears that for each integer $k\geq2$, there is **always** one integer $c$ that satisfies the inequalities below. Can this be proved?

$$\frac{3^k-2^k}{2^k-1}<c\leq \frac{3^k-1}{2^k}.$$

Note that for $k\geq2$ the lower bound is always a proper fraction and will never match an integer.

**Edit 28/1/2018** I have a [short proof here on Overleaf.](http://www.overleaf.com/read/xfxwtxcrppqs) **<--- It's done! Edit #28 is perfect!**

**edit** It looks like Waring's problem already has a solution. The sequence: https://oeis.org/A060692 "Corresponds to the only solution of the Diophantine equation 3^n = x*2^n + y*1^n with constraint 0 <= y < 2^n." This is equivalent to our $a+c$ for the Waring if statement. Oops, there is no proof that the diophantine equation is always $\leq 2^n.$ Here is a [proof sketch of Waring's](https://oeis.org/A297446)

Here is a brute force function:
aplusc[k_] := Module[{c}, c = 1; While[0 < 3^k - 2^k (++c)]; 3^k - 2^k (--c) + c]
where we increment $c$ until the calculation becomes negative, then we decrement by one to get $c$. We recalculate using that $c$ and add them together. A060692(k) equals this value.

**Closed form: [here.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/162520/973)** The brute force function illustrates the sawtooth pattern.

We can also create a(k), b(k), and c(k) using the same module. And we can use b(k) for the proof. Trivially, we can show b$(k) + 1 \leq 2^k.$

*edit.* Some more information and references: https://oeis.org/A002379
  PM

Comment: The difference between the RHS and the LHS is $1-\frac{3^k-1}{2^k(2^k-1)}<1 $.

Comment: I edited the question to remove the ambiguity as to what is actually being asked, and to improve slightly the presentation.

Comment: You write that "it appears" that what you are asking is true. Can you please elaborate in a comment what precisely you mean by this?

Comment: So, how far have you checked?

Comment: Another question. Have you (however summarily) checked that your question is not just a restatement of a well-known open problem?

Comment: Let $k>7$, $B=1.5^k$,  $A=\lfloor B \rfloor $ and $C=A+1=\lceil B \rceil$ then $A \lt B-0.75^k   \lt B  \lt B+0.75^k \lt C $  is an **open question** occuring in the Waring problem. An "inner" inequality $ B-0.75^k \lt {3^k+1\over 2^k+1}    \lt {3^k-1\over 2^k-1} \lt  B+0.75^k$ can be shown by some algebraical reworking. That ${3^k-1\over 2^k-1} \lt C$ might be a consequence of the Steiner-proof for the 1-cycle problem in the Collatz-problem but I don't remember exactly from the top of my head. All those are compatible with your second *floor* inequality.

Comment: After the edits, does this really deserve to be closed? (I would *at least* wait to act on that until the announced solution is posted.)

Comment: @Fred The most recent edit makes no sense.

Comment: @Fred I imagine both, but at least the description.  What do you mean by unit fractions? Anyway, my advice is that you do not include such trivial remarks, particularly since they do not seem to be illuminating.

Comment: (What does "the smallest part of a residue" mean? Currently those two recent edits read like nonsense and if you manage to turn them into something legible they do not seem to serve any purpose. Removing them would improve the post.)

Comment: Having no description makes no sense either Fred. There is no good reason to include that logical expression. There are variables there nor present anywhere else. People will wonder how to quantify them, and why bother to begin with. I suspect that's not the desired reaction.

Comment: Yes, can we please rewrite the edit in plain simple English?

Comment: @Fred I removed the end of the question: The description of $s,t$, and the equality of floors. None of this seems to add anything to the question and it was instead distracting. Plus, the prose needed some work. Seems better to remove it and leave the question as it currently looks.

Comment: Fred, the latest edit is nonsense. Better to remove it.

Comment: The additions to the question don't seem to serve any useful purpose.  Please stop making them.

Comment: @abx, you are absolutely right. We know $c$ is present by definition and there can be only one integer by your observation. We know that $c\in\mathbb{Z}$ is necessary for convergence because the denominators are relatively prime to each other.

Comment: 27th version of the question!

Comment: As expected, the "proof" is not.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, I spent two days chasing an error that turned out to be in my first use of the original Diaphantine equation. I had 1<= y instead of 0<y. It changed the upper bounds improperly. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 19):

It seems to me, that a sufficient proof for your first inequality is given in *Zudilin,W., A  new  lower  bound  for  ||(3/2)^k||* (manuscript at 2005$\,^\dagger$).

There he refers to a proof, where your $0.5^k$ (extracted from your ${3^k - 1\over 2^k}$ by writing ${3^k \over 2^k}-{1\over 2^k}=1.5^k-0.5^k$) was even replaced by the larger value $0.577^k$ . This means, that the integer value $c = \lfloor 1.5^k \rfloor$ is proven smaller than $ 1.5^k-0.577^k$. *(The      value $0.75^k$ in the Waring-conjecture however is still out of reach)*

The left expression in the *lhs* inequality in your concatenated inequality is larger than  *rhs*$-1$ (obvious by rewriting ${3^k-2^k\over 2^k-1}={3^k-1\over 2^k-1}-1 $ and then by expanding the geometric series) and the distance between the lhs and the rhs tends with increasing $k$ quickly towards $1$ and thus at most ***one*** integer value can be in the interval between *lhs* and *rhs* (namely the value $c=\lfloor (3/2)^k \rfloor $).

So I assume that with some additional work your full (concatenated) inequality might be provable with elementary means.

---

$\,^\dagger$ Preprint for "Journal de Theorie des Nombres de Bordeaux", it is available on Zudilin's homepage [here](http://wain.mi.ras.ru/PS/wr.pdf).

A view into S. Finch's book "mathematical constants" gives some quick insight, see [this link to google-books](https://books.google.de/books?id=Pl5I2ZSI6uAC&lpg=PP1&dq=%22powers%20of%203%2F2%20modulo%20one%22%20stemmler&pg=PA195#v=onepage&q=%22powers%20of%203/2%20modulo%20one%22%20stemmler&f=false):

Comment: Here is my latest Waring proof attempt: https://www.overleaf.com/read/xfxwtxcrppqs where I think the Y calculation can be addapted  to (4,2) below.

Answer (score 4):

To show $k\geq2$ per the comment in equality (3) on the other worksheet, we craft a logical expression which contains all the conditions:
$\text{lexp }=k\geq 2\land 1\leq a<2^k\land 1\leq b<2^k-1\land
\frac{3^k-1}{2^k-1}-\frac{b}{2^k-1}=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k-a\ 2^{-k}=c,$
where $a, b$ must be in their respective bounds or we do not have fractional parts and the final condition defines the common floor.

Using *Mathematica,* we reduce lexp using the six different solution patterns:
$\text{case }= \{\{a, b, c\}, \{a, c, b\}, \{b, a, c\}, \{b, c, a\}, \{c, a, b\}, \{c, b, a\}\}$
Table[{LogicalExpand[Reduce[lexp, case[[n]], Reals]]}, {n, 1, 
    Length[case]}]
$\begin{cases}
1&b=2^{-k} \left(2^k a-a-2^k+3^k\right)\land c=2^{-k} \left(3^k-a\right)\land k\geq 2\land a<\frac{2^{2 k}-3^k}{-1+2^k}\land 1\leq a\\
2&b=2^{-k} \left(2^k a-a-2^k+3^k\right)\land c=2^{-k} \left(3^k-a\right)\land k\geq 2\land a<\frac{2^{2 k}-3^k}{-1+2^k}\land 1\leq a\\
3&\frac{2^k b+2^k-3^k}{-1+2^k}=a\land c=2^{-k} \left(3^k-a\right)\land k\geq 2\land b<-1+2^k\land 2^{-k} \left(-1+3^k\right)\leq b\\
4&c=\frac{-b+3^k-1}{-1+2^k}\land 3^k-2^k c=a\land k\geq 2\land b<-1+2^k\land 2^{-k} \left(-1+3^k\right)\leq b\\
5&b=2^{-k} \left(2^k a-a-2^k+3^k\right)\land 3^k-2^k c=a\land k\geq 2\land \frac{-2^k+3^k}{-1+2^k}<c\leq 2^{-k} \left(-1+3^k\right)\\
6&3^k-2^k c=a\land -2^k c+c+3^k-1=b\land k\geq 2\land \frac{-2^k+3^k}{-1+2^k}<c\leq 2^{-k} \left(-1+3^k\right)\\
\end{cases}$
Since these cases are the only possible solutions, and since each case contains $k\geq2$, we can state, "All six cases produce identical values for $a, b, c$, iff $k\geq2,$ as required."$\square$
**29 Sep, 2017**
We have enough information from the cases above to solve Waring's problem. First, we extract three boundaries and explain their formulas:
1) Upper bound of the numerator $a$ of the fractional part, case(1), $a<\frac{4^k-3^k}{2^k-1} = 2^k (1-\delta (k)).$ This boundary increases proportionally to the decrease of $\delta (k).$
2) Lower bound of the common floor $c,$ case(5),
    $c>\frac{3^k-2^k} {2^k-1} = 2^k \delta (k).$
3) Upper bound of the common floor $c,$ case(5),
    $c\leq\frac{3^k-1} {2^k} = \frac{\delta (k)}{\frac{1}{3^k-1}+\frac{1}{2^k-1}}.$
Note: $\left\lceil 2^k \delta (k)\right\rceil=\left\lfloor \frac{\delta (k)}{\frac{1}{3^k-1}+\frac{1}{2^k-1}}\right\rfloor.$

From: [Waring's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem),
$g(k)=2^k+\left\lfloor \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^k \right\rfloor-2\ \ \ \ \text{ if }2^k \left\lbrace\left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^k \right\rbrace+\left\lfloor \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^k \right\rfloor\leq 2^k$,
where $\{\cdot\}$ is the fractional part.
Inspecting the "if" statement, we see that the product isolates the numerator of the fractional part, so we substitute $a$ and then substitute $c$ for the floor to get: $a+c\leq 2^k$. Empirically, this is solid. Note: $a+c$ is OEIS sequence [A060692](https://oeis.org/A060692).
Next, we substitute the upper boundary for $a$ and the lower boundary for $c$ and change to an equality: $ 2^k (1-\delta (k)) + 2^k\delta (k) =2^k\iff k\geq1\land k \in \mathbb{Z}.$ 
This is true because $(1-\delta (k))$ and $\delta (k)$ are proportions-of-the-whole, which retain the proportionality when multiplied by the same value; which affirms that the boundaries are rigid (and that the sum will not be greater than $2^k$).

Empirical: $\left\lfloor 2^k (1-\delta (k))\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{\delta (k)}{\frac{1}{3^k-1}+\frac{1}{2^k-1}}\right\rfloor =2^k$ holds up to $k=350000.$
**EDIT 29 Nov, 2017** New reductions.
Let exp3 = k $\geq2 \land (3^k - a)/(2^k) == (3^k - b - 1)/(2^k - 1) == c$, then we reduce using {a, b, c}, {b,c,a}, and {c,a,b} and back substitution. This results in three 3-variable diophantine equations to be proved:
    $$k>1\land b=\frac{a*2^k-a-2^k+3^k}{2^k}\land c=\frac{a \left(-2^k\right)+a-3^k+6^k}{2^k \left(2^k-1\right)}$$
    $$k>1\land c=\frac{-b+3^k-1}{2^k-1}\land a=\frac{b*2^k+2^k-3^k}{2^k-1}$$
    $$k>1\land a=\frac{c*2^k-c*2^{2 k}-3^k+6^k}{2^k-1}\land b=c \left(-2^k\right)+c+3^k-1$$

Comment: Hmm, aren't (1) and (2) identical? In that case you have only 5 condition-equations...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms, I just did all possible solutions and hadn't noticed. I double-checked my notebook and it is correct. Both b and c are calculated from a. Some of the others chain like 4 goes c from b, and a from c.

Comment: If this was no error, well - I just wanted to spot a possible typo etc. (I'm currently not able to decode your condition and results)

Answer (score 2):

We look at the small difference $\delta(k)$ of the the two fractions (which become very near by higher $k$)
$$\frac{3^k-1}{2^k-1}-\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k=\delta(k). \tag 1$$
Actually $\delta(k)$ is smaller than $1$ and approaches zero with higher $k$ which can be seen when expanded: 
$$\delta(k)=\frac{3^k-2^k}{2^k(2^k-1)}  \lt 1 $$ and is of order$ (3/4)^k$.

If we find now, that also the fractional values of the terms in eq (1) equal $\delta(k)$ thus  ***if we have*** that
$$\left\{ \frac{3^k-1}{2^k-1} \right\}-\left\{ \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{k} \right\}= \delta(k), \tag 2$$ 
***then*** it is obvious, that the two terms in (1) have also a common *floor* and we can write
$$\left\lfloor {3^k-1 \over 2^k-1}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\left({3 \over 2}\right)^k\right\rfloor. \tag 3$$

> The truth of this equality (3) for all $k \geq 2$ is what we want to show.

---

We introduce now shorter notations $$D(k)=\delta(k) \cdot 2^k =\frac{3^k-2^k}{2^k-1}=\frac{3^k-1}{2^k-1} -1  \tag {4.1}$$ and
$$ E(k)=\delta(k) \cdot \frac{(3^k-1)(2^k-1)}{3^k-2^k} = {3^k-1\over 2^k}
\tag {4.2} $$
and ***conjecture***, that there is always an integer $c$ between them:
$$D(k) \lt c \le E(k) \tag 5$$

***If*** that is indeed the case ***then*** we can write
$$\therefore\ c= \left\lfloor\frac{3^k-1}{2^k-1}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k\right\rfloor \text{for }k\geq2.\ \square$$

(Note: we didn't the required proof here, which actually seems out of reach. The motivation of this "answer" was just to make the original OP's claim and its ideas nicer to read)

Comment: By "residue", you mean "fractional part"? By "givens", you mean ... what?

Comment: I'm lost. What is assumed and what is proven here? In particular in the penultimate line are you claiming that there is an integer $c$ such that the inequalities hold? How does that follow from the preceding lines?

Comment: I still don't get it. Ok, *if* $c$ as in OP exists then it has to be equal to what you say, but I don't see a clear logical sequence of implications that proves that such $c$ always exists...

Comment: The language is odd (eg. does "started with" mean "assumed"? "verified" means "proved existence in ${\mathbb N}$ of"?). It seems as if you **assume** (by using the word "when") the equality in the second line to prove the existence of $c$ with the properties in OP, but  where is that assumption proven? I would recommend a complete rewrite using more standard language ("assume", "implies", "exists") and no logic symbols.

Comment: @Fred, since you mentioned to have current difficulties to formulate a narrative I've taken the liberty to edit your text (a bit radical, perhaps) hoping I do not completely change its meaning. It might not be correct because I do not arrive at a proof but only at a conjecture. Please expand further - or roll back if I did too much/did wrong interpretation. Hope all the best with you!

Comment: @FredKline, it seems that now we all agree on what is actually posted so far being a reformulation. Possibly a proof of the conjecture is on the way, or perhaps an empirical proof. I wish you a full and speedy recovery.